# Max and min of $f(x,y)=\sqrt[21]{y^4+x^3-3x^2-4y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I have this function:$$f(x,y)=\sqrt[21]{y^4+x^3-3x^2-4y^2}$$.

The domain of $f$ is all $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\{(x,y)\in R^2: y^4+x^3\ge 3x^2+4y^2\}$?

If I consider $f(x,0)=\sqrt[21]{+x^3-3x^2}$ for $x\rightarrow +\infty$ or $x\rightarrow-\infty$, $f$ is
unlimited up and  down  so max and min, if exist, are local.

If i calculate partial derivatives I found this points: $(0,\sqrt{2}),(0,-\sqrt{2}),(2,\sqrt{2}),(2,-\sqrt{2}),(2,0)$ but I have to consider also the origin?

Comment: Hints: the domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$ because the index of radical is odd. Moreover, note that $\sqrt[21]{\cdot}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a strictly incrising function so...

Comment: Yes, the maximum or the minimum, if exist, are local! :)